# Error constructing an rxjs/Observable

Tags: rxjs, systemjs, typescript2.0

Why does the following TypeScript code compile, but systemjs fails to load the dependencies correctly at runtime?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
let temp123 = new Observable<String>();
```

However, this works:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
let temp123 = new Observable<String>();
```

Specifically, the first code results in a .js file that contains the code:

```
var Observable_1 = require('rxjs');
var temp123 = new Observable_1.Observable();
```

but the second code generates this:

```
var Observable_1 = require('rxjs/Observable');
var temp123 = new Observable_1.Observable();
```

the line require('rxjs') fails with a 404 error because there is no file there.  Why is the typescript compiler able to resolve this, but systemjs cannot load it at runtime?

*Also noteworthy:* This problem only happens if I do certain things with the Observable.  For example, the following code works:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
let temp123: Observable<String> = null;
let xyz = temp123.first();
```

I can *use* the Observable, and call methods on it, without the TypeScript compiler generated a require('rxjs').  But I can't construct one, and I can't extend it either.

Versions:TypeScript 2.0.3, Systemjs 0.19.27, rxjs 5.0.0-beta.12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is the typescript compiler able to resolve this, but systemjs
>   cannot load it at runtime?

That's the way it works:

when you write `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` typescript finds `rxjs` folder in `node_modules` with `package.json` in it, which has

```
 "typings": "Rx.d.ts"
```

that's type declarations file for `rxjs`, and that file contains

```
  export { Observable } from './Observable';
```

which makes typescript to find another type declaration file in the same folder, `Observable.d.ts`, which has exported declaration for `Observable` class.

That's enough for your code to compile without errors.

If your code does not actually try to use `Observable` as a value, it will work, because typescript does [unused reference elision](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) - if `Observable` is used for type checking only, as in your second example, there will be no `require('rxjs')` call in generated javascrpt.

Now, SystemJS.

SystemJS does not have any default location to look for modules - it does not even recognise node_modules convention about `package.json` file with `main` property.

So, most likely, SystemJS in your example is configured like this:

```
    SystemJS.config({
        paths: {'npm:': 'node_modules/'},
        map: {'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'},
        packages: {
            rxjs: {
            }
        }
    });
```

So, the module `rxjs/Observable` imported by this line

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

is mapped to

```
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
```

because `rxjs` prefix matches `map` entry which together with `paths` maps it to `node_modules/rxjs`

`Observable` part comes through as is

`.js` extension is added because `rxjs` matches with `rxjs` package in systemjs config, and for any module that belongs to a package, SystemJS adds `.js` extension automatically unless `defaultExtension` is set to something else in that package config.

And it works, because the file `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js` exists.

And that import works with typescript too, because `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts` exists too.

Finally, this does not work at runtime

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

because it's mapped to `node_modules/rxjs` url, and there is no actual file there.

You can fix it by using `main` property in SystemJS package config:

```
        packages: {
            rxjs: {
                main: 'Rx.js'
            }
        }
```

Now it's mapped to `node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js`, and that file actually  exists and exports something named `Observable`, so it should work.

Checked with SystemJS 0.19.43, rxjs 5.0.3, typescript 2.1.5.

Comment: You are correct about my systemjs.config.  And your fix works.  Do you believe that addin 'main' to systemjs.package.config is a better or worse solution than changing my import statement?  Amazingly detailed answer, BTW.

Comment: I think adding `main` has better chances of keeping working when (and if) you will package your app using systemjs builder, but I haven't done that with rxjs myself, so I might be wrong. It would be interesting to know rxjs authors opinion on this, if they have any.

Comment: @artem. I've been wondering about `import from "rxjs"` vs `import from "rxjs/Observable"` for a while. Thanks for a very clear explanation.

Comment: That's an amazing description. I feel like you've explained the whole js module import procedure in one comment.